# Script string doesn't trim

Tags: javascript, string

Can anyone tell me why my strings doesn't trim. I have this code:

```
firstName = $('#form-create-user #first_name').val().trim().toLowerCase();
lastName = $('#form-create-user #last_name' ).val().trim().toLowerCase();

var initials = firstName.match(/\b\w/g) || [];
initials = ((initials.shift() || '') + (initials.pop() || '')).toLowerCase();
username = initials.concat(lastName);

$('#form-create-user  #username').val(username);
```

I would like the **username** to be generated from `firstname` and `lastname`, expecting Juan De la to generate `jdela`.

But the output is for example:

[image]

Comment: `.replace(/\s+/, "")` should work (Regex that removes all spaces)

Comment: @deceze Why is this question off-topic? There is enough code to reproduce the problem, imo it is correct...

Comment: @Mistalis "Trim" has a specific meaning, and this code is "trimming" just fine. OP didn't specify what else they expect to happen.

Comment: @deceze The question can be better formatted. The final expecting result can be easily guessed: he wants to generated a login based on firstname/lastname.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_trim_string.asp):

> The `trim()` method removes whitespace from **both sides of a string**.

It does not remove spaces **inside** a string.

---

You can use this regex to do the trick:

```
lastName = $('#form-create-user #last_name' ).val().replace(/\s/g, '').toLowerCase();
```

<sub>*Note this regex remove all whitespaces (including tabs and new lines).*</sub>

Answer (score 0):

trim will remove trailing and leading spaces not spaces between.

use

```
firstName = $('#form-create-user #first_name').val().trim().toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, "")
```

instead